# Structuring Django application

Tags: django, database-design, web-applications, web-application-design

I am currently working on designing a web application to be used by researchers to conduct reviews. In this application there are two groups of users - participants and administrators.

Only administrators can start a review and can assign any user or administrator to participate in the review as an admin or a screener. The general workflow for each review will be:

1. Search medical databases and import thousands of references.
2. Screen references based on title (number of reviewers/admins Screening can be 1 or multiple). Each reviewer will screen all references. Mark each reference as included or excluded.
3. Screen included references based on abstract. Same as above applies.
4. Source full-text as PDF and store for included references.
5. Screen included references based on full text. Same as above applies.
6. Create custom forms.
7. Extract data from included references.
8. Export data

Throughout the progress of the review machine learning on all of the references will be done. We will also require comprehensive logging throughout the review.

My question is this, how can I best split these sections into django apps and how should I structure the required databases.

Provisionally, I've thought about having these databases:

- Users. Stores info on screeners and reviewers and which projects a tenner and admin in.
- Project. Stores basic info on each project including data extraction form. One to many relationship with references table.
- References. Stores info about each reference including inclusion status and data extraction.

I don't know how to deal with the logging. How can I do this?

Is this a sensible split and if so how should I accordingly split the steps into apps.

Comment: I don't understand your question of how to detail with version control ? Django comes with default logging https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/ . But whats your  question about version control ?

Comment: @rrmerugu Logging in terms of Users activity ie. change in settings, deletion of references etc.

Comment: got it . @scutnex so whats the question about version control

Comment: @rrmeegu ignore the version control element, it's not important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing about Django is `apps` that you create with `manage.py startapp <myapp>` . Apps gives good control of modularising the code. You are on the right track in modularising the code.

Regarding your tables users, projects and references sounds reasonable from your explanation.

**If I were you, I would structure apps into something like this.**

```
apps/ 
    userprofile/ (users table )
    project/ (projects and references tables)
    activity/ (activity and notifications tables)
```

**Regarding logging**
Each activity like user edits , project edits or deletes can be captured via a post_ or pre_ signals https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/. User them to create an activity and based on the activity you can publish the single activity to multiple users as notifications ie., a single activity will trigger each  notification to multiple users who are participants in the event.

**In each app**

I prefer to use following structure inside each app :

```
userprofile/         
    __init__
    views.py
    tests.py
    signals.py # write the post_save pre_save post_delete pre_delete logics here
    managers.py  # take full leverage of managers, and custom querysets
    forms.py
    models.py
    urls.py
    admin.py
    tasks.py # for celery or tasks which will be used by queuing systems
    apps.py
```

**Regarding version the data**

Try the one which suites your requirement from here  https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/model-audit/